# Ubuntu Lenovo Y50 Intellij IDEA Crash

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I have a very strange problem with IntelliJ or Ubuntu (or maybe with my laptop - Lenovo Y50).

Starting IntelliJ crashes the computer, but it happens only in certain situations, here are the examples:

1. **Power Supply plugged in.** IntelliJ starts just fine, loads project and everything is ok.
2. **Power Supply not plugged in.** IntelliJ starts, there is a welcome screen, I can choose project, and then, while loading the project the whole computer crashes, just a black screen and the laptop is off instantly.
3. **Power Supply plugged in only to start IntelliJ.** Here is the weirdest situation. When PS is plugged in, IDE starts and loads project normally. Then when I exit IntelliJ, unplug the power supply (so it is like #2 scenario) and try to start IntelliJ again, load any project - no problems at all.

So the crash happens while loading the project (no matter what type) and power is not plugged it. It looks just as the power from the battery is suddenly cut. The problem was and is present in either Ubuntu 14.04 as well as 16.04.

I have looked all over the Internet and did not find any solution. I can provide IntelliJ and Ubuntu logs files.

**UPDATE**

I do not useany power saving mode.

I have also noticed that sometimes, even though I am only on battery (#2), it does not crash, but most times it does (about 90%).

Here is [dmesg log](http://pastebin.com/bdRvJnWp) from after the crash, I did not notice any errors; however, I am not good at linux logs.

@Andreas that may be what is happening here, for it happens when IDE is indexing and doing all the other checks on the project loading

Comment: Starting a program for the first time requires loading of the program into memory. Stopping and restarting a program will often not need that, because it's already in memory (cache). Sounds like your hard drive is overloading your power supply (battery), causing a catastrophic power failure. Any program that *extensively* uses the hard drive would cause the same result, if that is the culprit.

Comment: Yes, please provide the logs. Also, do you notice anything curious in the sys logs (which you can check using `dmesg`)?

Comment: Do you have any kind of power saving mode turned on?